# Unable to make graphQL API calls to AWS DynamoDB using graphql-tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to perform a createSite mutation in a JavaScript file as an alternative to using the AWS console and the App Sync API manager to make a direct query.

Using AWS console to make the query:

This query works perfectly fine. However, when I attempt to handle the query in my application using JavaScript, I encounter issues. Here's what I have so far in my apiTests.js JavaScript file:

```
`const AWS = require('aws-sdk');const AWSAppSyncClient = require('aws-appsync').default;const gql = require('graphql-tag');require('cross-fetch/polyfill');
```

```
const apiUrl = 'https://zhijioi4zrhavktrqnyebsmx2y.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql';const region = 'us-east-1';
```

```
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({url: apiUrl,region: region,auth: {type: 'AWS_IAM',credentials: AWS.config.credentials,},});
```

```
const mutation = gql(  mutation {     createSite(input: { domain: "example3.com", name: "test" }) {       id       domain       name     }   });
```

```
console.log('Executing the mutation');
```

```
client.mutate({ mutation }).then(result => {console.log('Mutation result:', result);console.log('Successfully created site:', result.data.createSite);}).catch(error => console.error('Error creating site:', error));`
```

The issue I'm facing is that when running this script, I receive a "Successfully created site" message, but it indicates that the result is of type "null". Here's the complete terminal output:

```
`Executing the mutation(node:1548) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.
```

```
Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScriptFor more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)Mutation result: { data: { createSite: null }, [Symbol(isOptimistic)]: true }Successfully created site: null`I attempted to change how I am passing arguments to createSite in the mutation const declaration, but as a newcomer to this technology, I am not confident in what I'm doing. I would appreciate any advice on how to continue using graphql-tag and edit this code so that it works, or if there is a completely different way to make queries from my project.
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry about the terrible formatting. I could not figure out how to just place code blocks, properly formatted and aligned. I tried ctrl + k when highlighting correctly formatted blocks of code, but that didn't work. It took me a lot of time to get this to be postable because I couldn't figure out the code formatting stuff, but somehow it accepted this.